# Seeking images of oil-level meters

Tags: data-request, images

I want to do some research on meter numerical identification. Where can I find information about the meters similar to the one shown below?

[image: Meter with dial with marked from 0 (minimum) to 10 (maximum)]

Where I can find other images of meters similar to the image above?

Comment: Sort of: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/ELECREAD/ I can provide more, but https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&q=electric+meter+pictures&tbm=isch&source=univ&client=firefox-b-1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif2Y_I55DhAhVJ04MKHdfcC-gQsAR6BAhgEAE&biw=1586&bih=771 is probably better

Comment: @BarryCarter Those ELECREAD images all seem to be corrupt

Comment: @JanDoggen I actually discussed with the OP, and the images, though not high quality, should not be corrupt.

Comment: @BarryCarter Well, take a look.

Answer (score 2):

You do not tell us how many images you need, I assume you only want some.
In that case just do an image search on [Google Images](https://images.google.com/).

When I did this Google responded with the suggestion that this is about a *gauge*:

[image]

Your next step would then be to replace the word *gauge* in the top search bar with more specific terms like *oil gauge* or *oil level meter* and repeat the search with that refinement.

Finally, click on *Visually similar images* to see all the results, and download them one by one.
Please note that there may be copyright issues depending on how you want to use those images.

Comment: Hello Jan! Would you like to nominate yourself as a candidate in this election: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/election ?

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thanks for the offer, but I don't want to invest the time. I'll just 'do' my writing/flagging on different SE sites...